# Mysqli cannot connect server

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having an issue with PHP Mysqli. I have this code in a script on two  servers:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
```

Server A: Dedicated Server

Server B: Virtual Private Server

Both servers have the exact same database, database users with permissions etc.

Here where the problem comes up:

Server A:

- Connect to Database of Server A: works flawlessly
- Connect to Database of Server B:

> **Warning**:  mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'abc'@'ip-123-456-789-101.ip.secureserver.net' (using password: YES) in **/home/abc/public_html/def/upload.php** on line **11**

Server B:

- Connect to Database of Server A: works flawlessly
- Connect to Database of Server B: error as above

To keep in mind, both servers have the same users, databases etc. I have already been on the phone with the hosting company but they cant help much.

Can anyone let me know what to check, what I can verify to resolve the issue?

Comment: it is connecting. you're providing the wrong credentials, so the client can't LOG IN to the db. if it couldn't connect, then it'd be "connection refused" or "connection timeed out"

Comment: are both servers networked internally?

Comment: You should post the commands and the parameters you use to connect to both of them.

May be your MySQL is configured to accept connections only through localhost.

Comment: both servers are hosted by the same hosting company. If they are networked internally there I cant tell. 
@MarcB: I have double checked the access information multiple times and they are correct.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Since both servers have the same configuration, why shouldn't they both get the same errors?

Comment: The database on Server B doesn't have appropriate `GRANT` permissions for the user `abc@serverB`.